# prestashop add custom field cms

Tags: field, prestashop

I have some trouble adding custom field to cms pages, I override CMS.php and AdminCmsController.php

```
class CMS extends CMSCore
{
    public $page_image;
    public $text_uno;
    public $text_due;
    public $text_tre;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'cms',
        'primary' => 'id_cms',
        'multilang' => true,
        'multilang_shop' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            'id_cms_category' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
            'position' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
            'indexation' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL),
            'active' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL),

            /* Lang fields */
            'meta_description' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
            'meta_keywords' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
            'meta_title' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
            'link_rewrite' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isLinkRewrite', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
            'content' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 3999999999999),

            'text_uno' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 3999999999999),
            'text_due' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 3999999999999),
            'text_tre' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 3999999999999),


            'page_image' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => false, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 3999999999999),
        ),
    );
}
```

and here AdminCmsController.php

```
class AdminCmsController extends AdminCmsControllerCore
{

    public function renderForm()
    {
.....

  array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->l('Testo uno'),
                    'name' => 'text',
                    'autoload_rte' => true,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'rows' => 5,
                    'cols' => 40,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}'
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Testo due'),
                    'name' => 'text_due',
                    'autoload_rte' => true,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'rows' => 5,
                    'cols' => 40,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}'
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Testo tre'),
                    'name' => 'text_tre',
                    'autoload_rte' => true,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'rows' => 5,
                    'cols' => 40,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}'
                ),


.....
}

public function postProcess()
    {
        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
        $update_images_values = false;


        foreach ($languages as $lang)
        {
            if (isset($_FILES['page_image']) && isset($_FILES['page_image']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['page_image']['tmp_name']))
            {
                if ($error = ImageManager::validateUpload($_FILES['page_image'], 40000000)){

                    return $error;
                }
                else
                {
                    $ext = substr($_FILES['page_image']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['page_image']['name'], '.') + 1);
                    $file_name = md5($_FILES['page_image']['name']).'.'.$ext;

                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['page_image']['tmp_name'],_PS_IMG_DIR_ .'cms'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name)){
                        return Tools::displayError($this->l('An error occurred while attempting to upload the file.'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $values['page_image'][$lang['id_lang']] = $file_name;
                    }
                }




                $update_images_values = true;
                $cms = new CMS((int)Tools::getValue('id_cms'));
                $cms->page_image = $file_name;
                $cms->update();

            }
        }

        parent::postProcess();
    }
```

i'm able to save the image but not the other text fields, where is the error?

Comment: Did you add the `text_uno`, `text_due` and `text_tre` in your `ps_cms_lang` table?

Comment: yes, as longtext type!